# Primeiro valor do select2 não é mostrado quando usa o i18next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, i18n

Estou fazendo a internacionalização com a lib i18next, tudo ocorre certo, ele traduz coloca os valores dentro do `select2`, porém o primeiro valor não é mostrado de forma alguma, mesmo eu abrindo o `select2` e clicando no primeiro item. Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head><title>Select2</title></head>
<body>
   <div>
      <label class="col-sm-12 text-white" style="text-align: left;" data-i18n="store.tipo"> </label>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <select id="selectTipo" class="form-control"></select>
         <br/>
         <br/>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script src="~/lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="~/lib/select2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="~/js/arquivo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         GetTipo();
      })
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript: **(arquivo.js)**

```
function GetTipo(){
var $selectTipo = $('#selectTipo');

$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.todos">', { value: "0", text: $(this).data('data-i18n')}));
$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.painel">', { value: "1", text: $(this).data('data-i18n') }));
$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.report">', { value: "2", text: $(this).data('data-i18n') }));
$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.notificacao">', { value: "3", text: $(this).data('data-i18n') }));
$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.auditoria">', { value: "4", text: $(this).data('data-i18n') }));
$selectTipo.append($('<option data-i18n="store.comboTipos.apresentacao">', { value: "5", text: $(this).data('data-i18n') }));
$selectTipo.val("0").trigger("change");
$selectTipo.select2();
}
```

IMAGEM:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JSFIDDLE: **(link resolvido)**

https://jsfiddle.net/danpadua/bq92ufq3/4/

Comment: Podes fazer um fiddle disto?

Comment: Feito, esta no final da pergunta

Comment: No fiddle com `select2` nem me aparece nada.

Comment: Pois eh, isso que é o problema, aqui no meu a lib select2 estava funcionando mais nao estava carregando os dados, agora nem ta mais funcionando

Comment: Agora está funcionando, olhem la. Tentem me ajudar o pq não carrega os itens na combo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui encontrar uma forma:

Como voce esta trabalhando com conteudo dinamico ocorre da biblioteca não conseguir tratar corretamente.

depois de montar o combo dinamico coloque esses dois caras abaixo no final, logo após ter adicionado os campos dinamicos.

```
$("#selectTipo").i18n();
$('#selectTipo').select2();
```

Comment: Vou testar......

Comment: Funcionou corretamente, atualizei o JsFiddle la

Comment: Eu tenho vários select2 e as vezes alguns não carregam o primeiro elemento vindo do i18n não mostra, o que mais poderia ser?

Comment: se todos forem dinamicos você precisa instancia-los após o carregamento